My Word-365 files seem to be saving to an odd place and won't autosave
I've only recently installed Office 365 / OneDrive on my own PC (never had any problem at work). All my Word files seem to save to a place called https://d.docs.live.net and I can't turn autosave on (it says "Save As A Word Documents (.docx)"). In fact it seems to be behaving very oddly. I've fiddled with various options, but I can't work out what's going on. This doesn't seem to happen with, for example, Excel files. Can anyone advise?

A friend of mine recently got the same problem. I thought it's a single document but it's for all Word files in OneDrive. The documents open with AutoSave off and no file name. If i edit and close, it asks me to save changes to d.docs.live.net

If you have checked your save settings and they are all set up correctly, I'd suggest repairing Microsoft office to see if this help. This is done through Control Panel > Add and Remove Programs > Microsoft office > Remove. This will open a menu allowing you to choose repair instead of install.
source - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-documents-is-saving-to-ddocslivenet-instead/9c1109c2-1740-4784-9aa2-11e07cdaf258
There is another suggestion on this link to disable one drive handling, but I have never done this so cannot comment on it.

That link is a bit out of date, I'm not sure it refers to Office 365. Nevertheless I did work out how to repair Office (actually listed as Microsoft 365 in the Programs and Features list), but sadly this had no effect on the problem.
